# Regular Expression to match two different URLs

Tags: regex

I am trying to match two different URLs using a regular expression for a google analytics filter and I can't seem to get it right.

I am try to match

**sub.domain.com** and **www.domain.fr**

This is the regular expression I used,

```
(sub\.domain\.com)|(www\.domain\.fr)
```

and I tried this as well

```
(sub\.domain\.com|www\.domain\.fr)
```

Neither of them worked.

What is the right regular expression to match the two urls?

Comment: Can you add code you have? because it works normally.

Comment: Not really using a code, it just goes in a filter box.

Comment: `(fr\.betclic\.com|www\.betclic\.fr)` works for me using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: This pattern works normally in Java.

Comment: Are you sure your filter box "eats" PCRE?

Comment: Thanks, twilson, I tested it with gskinner and it worked fine, the other regex tester I was using must have been broken

Comment: Vyktor, pretty sure it does... Thanks everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the script I was using to test it that was faulty, using gskinner helped. Thanks twilson

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `((fr|www)\.betclic\.(com|fr))` better?